# Joomla 2.5 and Virtuemart 2 custom field values send via e-mail

Tags: joomla2.5, virtuemart, custom-fields

I have a template override which is shows the products (with some jquery). I have a custom sendmail.php and it is send the choosen values correctly. But not the products custom fields value. I can not reach them. 
In the sendmail.php this fields available:

```
$userContact->shipname
$product->quantity
$product->product_parent_id ...
```

I can list all the custom field value with this in the sendmail.php:

```
foreach ($product->customfieldsCart as $field) {
echo $field->custom_value;
}
```

But I want the selected values only. In the normal ordering process, the invoice_items.php is working well (line 57-51):

```
if (!empty($item->product_attribute)){
if(!class_exists 'VirtueMartModelCustomfields'))
require JPATH_VM_ADMINISTRATOR.DS.'models'.DS.'customfields.php');
$product_attribute = 
VirtueMartModelCustomfields::CustomsFieldOrderDisplay($item,'FE');
echo $product_attribute;}
```

Pls help me, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the selected values of custom fields out of the product data in the product view.
As you said, you can get the values of all options of your custom fields, but the product data array does not store, which values/options were selected. this data could only come from the cart or invoice array.

in your case, i think you need to get the selected values with javascript, send them to your sendmail.php (ajax, json) and build your email with that data.